# Computing Gauss's of a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> The vector field given as $\vec{F}=\frac{\left \langle x,y,z \right \rangle}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}$
>
> The region $D=\left \{ a^{2}\leq x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\leq b^{2} \right \}$

I've some insights into this problem but would like to explore this further.

Evidently, $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=f\left ( x,y,z \right )$

But would it be easier, say, if we reformulate instead
$\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}\leq z\leq \sqrt{b^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}$
so we have
$\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}\leq g\left ( x,y \right )\leq \sqrt{b^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}$ as a graph of the surface z?

Spherical coordinates would greatly simplify the crux of the matter here.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the vector $\vec F=\frac{\vec r}{r^2}=\hat r$, where $\hat r$ is the radial unit vector.  The divergence of $\vec F$ for $0<a\le r\le b$ is

$$\begin{align}\nabla \cdot \vec F&=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial (r^2F_r)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\frac{\partial (\sin \theta F_{\theta})}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\frac{\partial ( F_{\phi})}{\partial \phi}\\\\
&=\frac2r\end{align}$$

since $F_r=1$ and $F_{\theta}=F_{\phi}=0$.

The volume integral of $\nabla \cdot \vec F$ over the volume between a sphere of radius $b$ and a sphere of radius $a$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_a^b\frac2r\,r^2\sin \theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\&=4\pi(b^2-a^2)\end{align}$$

Finally, the Divergence Theorem asserts that

$$\begin{align}\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV&=\oint_S \hat n \cdot \vec F\,dS\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi (\hat r \cdot \hat r) \,b^2\sin \theta \,d\theta\,d\phi+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi (-\hat r \cdot \hat r) \,a^2\sin \theta \,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=4\pi(b^2-a^2)\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Isn't it just $\vec{F} = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}$

Comment: Are you using spherical coordiantes for the vector surface integral?

Comment: @Dan The spherical unit vector $\hat r = \vec r/r$.  So, you are correct.  - Mark

Comment: @needhelp Yes, I have used spherical coordinates throughout the entire development including the surface integral evaluation.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: OK I thought so, just making sure

Comment: Let X be the parameterisation in Spherical coordinates.
What is your $F(X(\theta,\phi))?$
I arrive at a huge mess.

Comment: @Dr.MV Got it. Mathematica paved the way out of the mess.

Comment: Pleased to hear!